# Change background color of actionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I'm trying to change the color of the ActionBar.

If I use this code:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#BA0000</item>
</style>
```

It works (for a few milliseconds I can see the red color) but crashes and throws this error: `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

If I use this code:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#BA0000</item>
</style>
```

It doesn't crash but also doesn't change the color.

Comment: This has been asked a million times.

Comment: Don't add answers into your question

Comment: @jonrsharpe So no answer is better than an answer?

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate - if you have a new answer, add it to the dupe. Alternatively, it looked like you were asking a secondary question, which should be a separate question (although you should do more checking whether that is a duplicate than you did for this one).